# Javascript regex returns null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match this url:

https://play.spotify.com/user/randomuser/playlist/71ljVu3Ejccu2PzW6iXv0G

where random user and the ending id are changing.

I want to verify that the url is indeed a play.spotify.com link and matches that format.

I have this javascript function:

```
var verify = function(url){
    var re = new RegExp("(https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/user\/\w+?\/playlist\/\w+)", "g");
    var result = re.exec(url);
    console.log(result);
}

verify("https://play.spotify.com/user/useruser/playlist/71ljVu3Ejccu2PzW6iXv0G");
```

When I tested it out using a regex tester, it seems to work correctly:

[image]

The output of the console.log, however, is just `null`.

What am I doing wrong in the javascript? Why isn't the url properly matching?

Comment: [Don't use the `RegExp` constructor, use a regex literal.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression)

Comment: You also might want to replace the domain name's `.`s into `\.`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> "(https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/user\/\w+?\/playlist\/\w+)"
> ```

You're escaping the characters `/` and `w` here, which is not necessary in a string literal. Your string is equivalent to

```
"(https://play.spotify.com/user/w+?/playlist/w+)"
```

which obviously now is not the regex that you're looking for.

[Don't use the `RegExp` constructor, use a regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression):

```
var re = /(https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/user\/\w+?\/playlist\/\w+)/g;
```

If you really needed to use `new RegExp` for some reason, you'd have to escape the backslash character in your string: `new RegExp("(https://play.spotify.com/user/\\w+?/playlist/\\w+)", "g")`.

Comment: In that last regex you forgot to escape the first \w+? as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `RegExp` constructor, and can use the `string.match(regex)` function to get the result:

```
var verify = function(url) {
  var regex = /https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/user\/\w+?\/playlist\/\w+/g;
  var result = url.match(regex);
  console.log(result);
};

// Passes, logs the URL:
verify("https://play.spotify.com/user/useruser/playlist/71ljVu3Ejccu2PzW6iXv0G");

// Fails, logs null
verify("https://play.spotify.com/useruser/playlist/71ljVu3Ejccu2PzW6iXv0G");
```

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/bupuxubefo/edit?js,console)